# getting an empty array for filter/search text in mongo db using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying out search functionality in mongo database using node js.my result array always empty. I shared my code here. Someone help me to find whats wrong.
after searching I am getting an empty array [] in my console.

models/contact.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
cid: String,
name: {type: String, index: true},
phon: Number,
contactwith:  {type: String, index: true}
 });
 module.exports = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema);


   mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema).ensureIndexes(function(err) {
      if (err)
          console.log(err);
       else
          console.log('create contact index successfully');
     });
```

Controller/contact.js

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var Contact = mongoose.model('Contact');

  var ContactController = function(app,mongoose){   
    app.post('/search',function(req,res){
    var query = req.body.searchbx;
    console.log(query);
    var dbsearch = Contact.find({$text: {$search: query}}, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}).sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}});
    console.log(dbsearch);

    Contact.find({$text: {$search: query }}, function (err, results){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        if(results){
            console.log('in results')
            console.log(results)
            res.render("search",{results: results});
        }
    })

  });
 }
module.exports = ContactController;
```

in jade file

```
form(id="search-filter" method ="POST" action="/search")
input#search-bx(type='text', name='searchbx' placeholder="search here")
input(type="submit", value="Search")
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are the beginner to nodeJS. Welcome :)

You did lot of things except 2 main things that is important!

1. You have used POST method for search action. As per HTTP Standards, you have to use GET or PATCH for search related actions

Please Read: 
http://restfulapi.net/http-methods/

2. You have tried for text search. $text queries to work, mongodb needs to index the field with an text index.
   You want to do some one changes in your mongoose

   {fields: {type: [String], text: true}

REF:
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-text/

Here is the simple and clean code:
you can do modification based on the sample

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', {
    name : {type : String, unique: true,  text: true},
    location: {type: String}
});

Controller:
app.get('/api/todo/search/:searchKey', function (req, res) {
        var searchKey = req.params.searchKey;
        if (!searchKey) {
            return res.send({ reason: 'searchKey required' });
        }
        Todo.find({
            $text: { $search: searchKey }}, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500);
                    return res.send({ reason: err.toString() });
                } else if (result && result.reason) {
                    return res.status(400).send(result);
                }
                return res.status(200).send(result);
            });
    });
```

All the Best!!!